# Converting text file to float and into dictionary to find frequency

Tags: python, dictionary

I am given a text file that is all words with no punctuation, just spaces separating the words. My goal is find and print the word that has the highest frequency in the file along with its frequency. I am able to do this no problem with a similar problem that involves a text file with many numbers but cannot get this to work without getting an error.

This is my attempt at getting it to work. it works fine for the other text file using int() instead of float(). The two things that I think might work are using split() or using .append(). I am not quite sure how to properly integrate them into this. I have read previous posts that are similar, but either they do not involve using a dictionary to calculate frequency or they are not specifically words.

```
words = {}
myfile = open("HAPPY.txt")

for x in myfile:
    y = float(x.strip())
    if y not in words:
        words[y] = 1
    else:
        words[y] = words[y] + 1

for x in words:
    if words[x] == max(words.values()):
        print(x, words[x])
```

The error i receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jekni\PycharmProjects\Python Class\Homework\HW 7.py", line 31, in <module>
    y = float(x.strip())
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Once upon a time in a faraway land there lived a man and a woman'
```

**edit**

sample of text file:
Once upon a time in a faraway land there lived a man and a woman
They lived in a humble cottage in the heart of the woods where they found peace and happiness in the simplicity of their life

sample of number file I mentioned earlier in post:
69
35
31
75
87
56
55
67
30

Comment: Why do you use `float()` at all?

Comment: you are trying to convert string 'Once upon a time in a faraway land there lived a man and a woman' to float. It fails.

Comment: what does `float` or `int` for that matter, have to do with frequency of strings in a text? There is no need to convert the input to a numeric int/float

Comment: I am using float() to convert the string in the text file because when i tried without using the float() it returned just the whole text file with a number "1" after each line.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. Please add the expected output for each file input.

Comment: You seem surprised that you're getting an error when you try to convert arbitrary text to float (for no apparent reason). Hint: take a look at the Counter class in the *collections* module

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to convert the file to a string you need to use the read() method.
I changed your code and also add a split method so it make an array with all the words

```
words = {}
myfile = open("HAPPY.txt") #Edited

myfile = myfile.read().split()

for y in myfile:
    if y not in words:
        words[y] = 1
    else:
        words[y] += 1

for x in words:
    if words[x] == max(words.values()):
        print(x, words[x])
```

(I dont know how you file would look like so you may also have to split line jumps)

Comment: Did you notice the NameError exception when you tested this?

Comment: working just fine for me.

Comment: Impossible. *open(HAPPY.txt)*

Comment: oh I see you could have started by this instead of being passive agressive like this. something like: "you forgot to put the quote" would be more polite.

Answer (score -1):

The Counter utility class from the collections module is ideal for this:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("HAPPY.txt") as text:
    counter = Counter(text.read().split())
    print(*counter.most_common()[0])
```

**Output:**

```
a 5
```

If you prefer not to import anything then:

```
d = dict()

with open("HAPPY.txt") as data:
    for word in data.read().split():
        d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1

print(*sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[-1])
```